# How to scale a ImageButton in Android so that three buttons fit into row?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem to add three buttons into a row of my `LinearLayout`. It looks like

[image]

i want that the three buttons are scaled so that it fits into the row.

My xml-definition is:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="left"
    >

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_select_instance"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/searchid_blau"         
     android:onClick="selectInstanceAction"/>


    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_select_from_scanner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/qr_code_blau" 
     android:onClick="selectInstanceWithScannerAction"/>

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_select_from_scanner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/qr_code_blau" 
     android:onClick="selectInstanceWithScannerAction"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight=1
```

in each of your ImageButton

Answer (score 2):

first add *weightSum* to the LinearLayout

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

then add *layout_weight* for each Button yo have

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and change the Button width to 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add attribute `android:weightSum="3"` to your liner layout and in ImageButton`s change

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

Thats all =)